# Want Woocomerce products in shop to be visible, but not buyable

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I am looking for an option to show products in a Wordpress woocommerce webshop, but the customers should not be able to buy it online.

My customer sells antiques and some of it are too fragile to ship, but she would like the product to be shown in the webshop.

Is there any easy way to do this? There are 1500 products, and I would very much not like to add weight class to all the products manually.

Right now some products are private, but she would like that "in between" option, to show some products in the shop, buy they should not be possible to buy online.

Hoping for help.

Best regards Berit

Comment: Hey You want something like this URL,https://greenmount.foundersapproach.com/our-work/
I have done so far in my project

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the add to cart button and disable the checkout function.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_is_purchasable', '__return_false');
remove_action('woocommerce_single_variation', 'woocommerce_single_variation', 10); 
remove_action('woocommerce_single_variation', 'woocommerce_single_variation_add_to_cart_button', 20);
```

[more info here](https://react2wp.com/remove-hide-add-to-cart-button-in-woocommerce-while-disabling-keeping-purchase-functionality/)

It worked for me.
If it not works with you, you should explain more or give more details about your WC setup

before
[image]

after
[image]